# Select first div after find_all when searching for text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

**THE PROBLEM**

I am trying to collect text contents within the div tag at two instances in this website https://doffin.no/Notice/Details/2022-311143. The specific content I want to scrape has differing locations on every variation of this page (e.g., if I want to open a similar page but for another contract), and it seems there are numerous elements with the same "tag" (i.e., "div" and class "eps-text). However, the following strings always appears in front of the information I am looking for:

1. "Navn og Adresser" (h3)
2. "Den valgte leverandørens navn og adresse" (h3)

**WHAT I TRIED**

I tried to use findNext with the text strings "Navn og Adresser" and "Den valgte leverandørens navn og adresse", but it yields no result. I understand it is because I search for text instead of a tag.

**MY CODE**

```
    ua = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    page = requests.get(new_url, headers=ua)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
    a = soup.find("h3", text="Navn og adresser")
    print(a.findNext('div',{'class':'eps-text'}))
    b = soup.find("h3", text="Den valgte leverandørens navn og adresse")
    print(b.findNext('div', {'class':"eps-text"}))
```

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT**
To illustrate exactly what I am looking for, please see the screenshot I added. In this case I want "Sarpsborg kommune" and "Damslet Skilt AS".

[image]

[image]

**FINAL PLEA**

As you probably understand, I am super inexperienced with python, so any help is super appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

your_text = (
    BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(
            "https://doffin.no/Notice/Details/2022-311143"
        ).text,
        "html.parser"
    ).select_one(".eps-sub-section-body > div").getText()
)
print(your_text)
```

Output:

```
Sarpsborg kommune
```

---

EDIT:

You've asked for `Damslet Skilt AS`, which wasn't in the original version of the question, but here it is:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

damslet_css = "div.eps-section:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(7) > div:nth-child(1)"

find_damslet = (
    BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(
            "https://doffin.no/Notice/Details/2022-311143"
        ).text,
        "html.parser"
    ).select_one(damslet_css).getText()
)

print(find_damslet)
```

Output:

```
Damslet Skilt AS
```

Comment: That works - thanks! I also need to get another data point - "Damslet Skilt AS" a bit further down on the page. Do you know how I could go about to find that data point?

Comment: Sometimes this does not work, because the website setup is not equal for different contracts. As described in the initial text - the thing that remains is that "Navn og Adresser" (h3) "Den valgte leverandørens navn og adresse" (h3) is always before the information I want to find. Can you help with this?

Comment: No, I'm done with this question and I'm tired of you adding/removing the accepted answer mark.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm very inexperienced so although I thought it worked earlier it did not after all. Appreciate the help so far either way!